# DocuSign- How to populate fields already present in PDF before sending the envelope in c#

Tags: c#, docusignapi

In attached pdf i need to fill the information "Name of the facility/provider", Marked checked "Medicaid" checkbox tec. Any help much appreciate.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I was passing wrong role name.

Answer (score 0):

If the original PDF has these fields as meta-data (not just visually) you can use the [PDF Form Fields Transformation](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/pdf-transform/#:%7E:text=PDF%20form%20field%20transformation%20enables,from%20which%20they%20were%20generated.) option and DocuSign will automatically find them and generate them.

If not, you can use [anchor strings](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/auto-place/) (like the text "Name of the facility/provider") but you'll have to add the tabs yourself and set the **anchorString** property and potentially the offsets to position it correctly.

Comment: Hi Inbar, thanks for your answer. However using field transformation is not resolving the issue. I created one template in DocuSign and added few fields in the templates which i want to populate dynamically.   
           Text providerName = new Text
            {
                TabLabel= "ProviderName",
                Value="XYZ"
            };
            Text patientName = new Text
            {
                TabLabel = "PatientName",
                Value = "XYZ"
            };